# javascript object creation for mongodb query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Tried to make the javascript object for mongodb query but javascript object auto quoted the $and property(due to dollar sign) which in result query error.

```
var array = [{
    name: 'raiwind'
  },
    {
      "rating.ratingGain": 9
    }];
  var filter = {
    $and: array
  };
  console.log(filter); //output// { '$and': [ { name: 'raiwind' }, { 'rating.ratingGain': 9 } ] }
```

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Quoted `$and` is syntactically correct in Mongo

Comment: it is not working in aggregation @Héctor

Comment: @SergeK. mongodb aggregation do not allow quotes for $and (like '$and') and generate error

Comment: @user3595398 Can you post the actual error and the corresponding code please ?

Comment: sorry, there was some syntax error . you are correct @Héctor.

Comment: Nice, glad to help

Comment: BTW the quotes you were seeing are added by the `console.log`.

Comment: yes, quotes are added by console.log @SergeK.